# Django Pillow, save image as jpeg does not seem to work

Tags: django, forms, image, upload, python-imaging-library

Goodmorning,

I'm using Pillow to resize and save an image within a Django model called Post. The image is retrieved from the imagefield, get's a check to see if it is RGB or not, if not the image is converted to RGB.

Finally, I'm creating a thumbnail from the original image and try to save this in the MEDIA_ROOT.

Even though the image get's uploaded, it doesn't seem to convert the image to jpeg.

I followed the tutorial here [Django 2+ edit images with Pillow](https://medium.com/@panzelva/django-2-edit-images-after-uploading-with-pillow-9009e5bfa482) and I'm trying to fit it to my needs.

What am I missing here?

## models.py

```
import os

from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from PIL import Image
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
class Post(models.Model):

# Custom validators
title_validator_specialchar = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[\s*\d*a-zA-Z]{5,60}$', message="The title can't contain any special characters")

category = models.ForeignKey('Category',default=1, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators=[title_validator_specialchar])
content = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #On save, update timestamp date created
    if not self.id:
        self.created_at = timezone.now()
    self.updated_at = timezone.now()
    return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


def resize_image(instance, **kwargs):

if instance.image:

    # we are opening image with Pillow
    img = Image.open(instance.image)

    # convert image to RGB
    if img.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'):
        img = img.convert('RGB')

    # img.size is tuple with values (width, height)
    if img.size[0] > 320 or img.size[1] > 640:
        
        # Using thumbnail to resize image but keep aspect ratio
        img.thumbnail((320, 640), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        
        # saving to original place
        # instance.image.name is in %Y/%m/%d/<name> format
        output = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, instance.image.name)
        img.save(output, "JPEG")

# Connect the signal with our model
post_save.connect(resize_image, Post)
```

Answer (score 0):

A signal handler receives the sender as the first argument, which in case of the `post_save` signal is the model class, not the model instance.

So the argument `instance` of `resize_image()` should be named `sender` and does not contains what you want. Here is how you get the actual instance:

```
def resize_image(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    if instance and instance.image:
        ...
```

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the explanation, I should read more about signals in general. However this did not solve my problem. Since I had to find a solution, I added django-imagekit and use the ProcessedImageField

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't find what I needed to get this to work, I decided to use django-imagekit.

I'm using the ProcessedImageField and the ResizeToFill processor on my model;

## models.py

```
image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d/', processors=[ResizeToFill(384, 216)], format='JPEG', options={'quality': 60}, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens beacuse You explicitly call img to save in the mediaroot but instance.image stays still. So django will save that image also. So I think You have to change the instance.image attribute rather than calling img to save. For that you have to use django InMemorUploadedFile

```
import io
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
import sys
```

```
if instance.image:

# we are opening image with Pillow
img = Image.open(instance.image)

# convert image to RGB
if img.mode not in ('L', 'RGB'):
    img = img.convert('RGB')

# img.size is tuple with values (width, height)
if img.size[0] > 320 or img.size[1] > 640:
    
    # Using thumbnail to resize image but keep aspect ratio
    img.thumbnail((320, 640), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    
    # saving to original place by changing instance.image. django will save it 
    #automatically in mediaroot
    img_io = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(img_io, "JPEG")
    instance.image = InMemoryUploadedFile(img_io, 'ImageField', 'image.jpeg', 
                    'image/jpeg',sys.getsizeof(img_io), None )
```

we can't pass the Image object directly  to inastance.image because it raises an error.
so we have to convert img to InMemoryUploadedFile object.